# How to use Triggers for Logging History of database changes in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, logging, triggers

How can one use Triggers for Logging History of database changes in MySQL?
If it is possible, can one create a separate database for trigger tables for tracking history of other Db tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you could use [this](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/logging-queries-with-mysql/) approach instead to do query logging

Comment: I also nned the fetch the data from that tracking table so that i can see the changes anytime I Need

Comment: @Cheese I am not aware of assembling AOP with PHP neither I am aware of AOP concept... ny other Way?

Comment: not sure... do some investigation and post an answer if you find it out